# Is this a valid Windows update page

Tags: windows, malware, dns-spoofing, spoofing

In my chrome browser if I google for Windows Update the first hit is

windowsupdate.microsoft.com/‎

When I click on it I am redirected to

http://www.update.microsoft.com/windowsupdate/v6/thanks.aspx?ln=en&&thankspage=5

Now this to me looks like my machine has been hijacked and somebody with bad graphics ability has redirected my page to this dodgy graphic telling me to use windows update.

However I cant find details anywhere.  On some other machines I get a different (slightly more professional looking) page.

Can anyone tell me if this is a spoof page due to malware or virus on the machine.  My Norton isn't showing anything?

Comment: Yup, it's legitimate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a genuine Microsoft Update site. If you go to any Microsoft KB article you'll see the link in the INTRODUCTION section ([example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2792100)). All old Windows Update addresses such as `windowsupdate.microsoft.com` and `windowsupdate.com` now redirect to the new `update.microsoft.com`.

The new domain seems to be a policy of unifying the update site for Microsoft's products under one name: Microsoft Update. As for the bad graphics and malware suspicions, a malware wouldn't really tell you to use a Microsoft application to update system. A malware usually tells you to click on shady links or asks you to download some "update helpers".

Comment: any proof of this?

Comment: @2xMax You want a proof that `*.microsoft.com` domains are legitimate Microsoft domains?

Comment: I was unsure that windowsupdate.com is a valid ms domain since only indirect pages like this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2792100 provided the information about this host. I expected to see something like an msdn article with the full list of WU domains.

Answer (score 4):

To complete what @Adnan says: yes, the page is legitimate, *however*, it is an HTTP-only page, so it could *potentially* be hijacked (without HTTPS, attackers have ways to present you with fake pages), although it is rather unclear what an attacker could gain that way. Either way, using the menu entry to reach the update site is safe from external interference (or, at least, as safe as these things can be).

As for graphics abilities... well, even Microsoft designers are not necessarily tasteful.

Comment: I'm not sure what's "unclear" about what an attacker would hope to gain by spoofing Windows Update. They could be wanting to re-direct the user to a malicious page hosting browser exploits, phish a user for data and/or credentials by claiming Windows Update requires registration, or simply trick them into downloading and running a fake update, etc. I suppose the only thing "unclear" to me is which among the plethora of options a random attacker might choose.

Comment: Well, isn't it s clear "gain" to be able to present a fake list of updates to download, and let the user download malware instead?

Comment: and @Iszi hits again. Thomas is saying it's unclear what the attacker could gain by highjacking the page and telling you to use the official Windows Update application on your computer. _That's_ what is unclear. Clear for you now?